# launching windows phone via browser

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

i am new to windows phone app development. i have downloaded a sample from the url http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec

i have tried below : 
when i paste alsdkcs://helloworld in IE browser running on windows 8 desktop, the app is launching.

but  when i paste the same in IE running on windows phone 8,the app is not launching instead its says unsupported address.

Comment: are you sure that you targeted WP8.1?

Comment: no, the target is wp8 . have you tried in wp8.1 dude.

Comment: nop as the doc says it does support only for 8.1

Comment: is it possible to do target below 8.1 ? .. please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Hell... I got the answer. It's working if I call via javascript

```
 function loadwindowsphone() {
             window.location =
            `enter code here`       'alsdkcs://hd';
```

```cs
         }      <input id="btnwindowsphone" type="button" class="button" name="" value="open windows phone"      onclick="javascript:loadwindowsphone();" /><br /><br />
```

```cs
function loadwindowsphone() {
                     window.location = 'alsdkcs://hd';
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

WP8 IE result in "Unsupported address" error message : IE only treat URL as HTTP/HTTPS URL, not check against the custom URL scheme list like iOS Safari.

If you want check, you can use UC browser or others.